# Dollar/Riyal currency converter in Python

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

````
us = 'US Dollar [$]'
sr = 'Saudi Riyal [S.R]'
    
    # Questions for the user :)
    print('Which Currency You Want?\n')
    print("1 - Saudi Riyal To US Dollar\n")
    print("2 - US Dollar To  Saudi Riyal\n")
    
    def convert():

        amount = input('Please enter the amount: ')

        def option1():

                calculation = val_am  * 3.75
                print('calculating...')
                time.sleep(3)
                print('The amount is', calculation, 'S.R')

        def option2():
                calculation =  val_am  / 3.75
                print('calculating...')
                time.sleep(3)
                print('The amount is', str(calculation) + '$')

        if amount > '10000':
            print("Larg Amount, Try Again")
            while True:
                amount2 = input('Please enter the amount: ')
                try:
                    val_am = int(amount2)
                    if val_am > 10000:
                        print('Larg Amount, Try Again')
                    else:
                        
                        if val == 1:
                            return option1()
                        if val == 2:
                            return option2()
                            break;  
                except ValueError:
                    print('This Not A Number')
    
    while True:
        option = input("Which one?: ")
    
        try:

            val = int(option)
            if val > 2:
                print('Sorry, There\'s Only Two Options')
            
             else:
                convert()
                break;
        except ValueError:
            print('Sorry, This not a number!')
            
        
                
           
    input('Press Enter To Continue...')
```
````

Comment: Are you after user experience, correctness, or readability?

Comment: @ted, we consider all of those to be fair game for review here.  Any and all aspects of the code can be critiqued.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `option1` and `option2` functions are a bit confusing in that they use `val_am`, but up until that point, `val_am` hasn't been assigned yet. This forces me to read ahead a bit
then scroll back a bit if I'm trying to follow the data, and also opens up the possibility of accidentally calling one of those two function before `val_am` has been set if you refactor your code later. To avoid relying on variables being defined in the enclosing scope, I'd pass the required data in as an argument:

```
def option1(val_am):  # Then do the same to option2
    calculation = val_am * 3.75
    print('calculating...')
    time.sleep(3)
    print('The amount is', calculation, 'S.R')
```

Then

```
if val == 1:
    return option1(val_am)  # Explictly provide the required data as an argument
if val == 2:
    return option2(val_am)
```

If you want to get a little advanced, those functions can actually be combined. There are two differences between the functions:

- `option1` uses multiplication, while `option2` uses division.
- `option1` prints out `'S.R'` for the currency, while `option2` prints a `'$'` at the end.

These differences can be accounted for by making them additional parameters of the function:

```
def option(val_am, converter_op, currency):
    calculation = converter_op(val_am, 3.75)
    print('calculating...')
    time.sleep(3)
    print('The amount is', calculation, currency)
```

Then, it would be used as either:

```
if val == 1:
    return option(val_am, lambda x, y: x * y, "S.R")
if val == 2:
    return option(val_am, lambda x, y: x / y, "$")
```

or,

```
import operator as op

if val == 1:
    return option(val_am, op.mul, "S.R")
if val == 2:
    return option(val_am, op.truediv, "$")
```

The difference between the two ways is how the multiply/divide is communicated to the `option` function. In the first case, I'm passing a `lambda` function, in the second, I'm making use of the `operator` module which are basically normal functions wrapping the operators like `*` and `/`. Prefer `operator`. I showed the `lambda` version in case you already knew about `lambda`s.

This also isn't a major improvement here, but as functions become more complicated, and you begin writing different functions that look very similar, it's helpful to know how to generalize them and make single functions more generally useful.

I would also take the `option` function(s) out of `convert`. Once you've made `val_am` a parameter of the function, there's no longer any reason it should be inside of `convert`. Having it in there is just making the function longer than it needs to be and thus harder to read.

---

Similarly as above, I would also make `val` a parameter of `convert`:

```
def convert(val):
    . . .

if val > 2:
    print('Sorry, There\'s Only Two Options')     
else:
    convert(val)  # Pass it in
```

A good general rule of thumb to follow: If a function requires some data, supply it as an argument to the function. It makes it clearer where data is coming from, and prevents you from attempting to use data before it's been set. Both of those become increasingly important as your code becomes more complicated.

---

`if val > 2:` isn't checking for negative numbers being entered. If you're going to print a warning for numbers higher than `2`, you might as well also warn against other illegal input. I'd write that as:

```
if 1 <= val <= 2:
    convert(val)    
else:
    print('Please enter either 1 or 2')
```

Also note, you had the string `'Sorry, There\'s Only Two Options'` previously, and are escaping the quote using `\'`. That's not necessary though. You can have single quotes unescaped if you use double outer quotes:

```
print("Sorry, There's Only Two Options")  # Runs fine
```

---

```
return option2()
break;
```

- Once you've `return`ed from a function, you leave it at that point. That means that that `break` will never be reached. A good IDE (like Pycharm) will warn you of oddities like this using warnings.
- The `;` isn't necessary here. You should avoid `;` altogether though. It's really never needed, and just adds to noise on the line.

Comment: Thanks i appreciate your support, also if you could explain specifically where should the function(s) be and the conditions like the if statement etc., You have my thanks again
@Carcigenicate

Comment: @MohammedAhmed First day of classes today, so I'll see if I have time later. The functions should be all "top level" though; not inside of anything else. And everything else is the same as where you already have it. I showed the `if` part because I changed it, not because it should be moved.